# Android Add Button Top Of Listview

Tags: android, listview, button

Sorry, I'm a newbie :(

How to add a `Button` at the top of a `ListView` and Style like here:
[This Image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/823/devicetb.png/)

Comment: Could refer to this [link](http://blog.maxaller.name/2010/05/attaching-a-sticky-headerfooter-to-an-android-listview/)

Comment: [This](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/gingerbread-release) is the source code of the original alarm clock app in Gingerbread. You can see that the used button style is not a standard one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i'ts better when you use a LinearLayout first with vertical orientation, and put a Button, and put a ListView. The LinearLayout will your "Content Wrapper" like this:
main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <Button 
      android:text="Button"
      android:id="@+id/button1" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   <ListView 
      android:id="@+id/listView1" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:entries="@array/list"/>       
 </LinearLayout>
```

and a string-array for entries:

```
<string-array name="list">
    <item>Entry1</item>
    <item>Entry2</item>
    <item>Entry3</item>
    <item>Entry4</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I just want to confirm that, is the `Button` always on top of the `ListView` that even when `ListView` is scrolled, the `Button` is still there or the `Button` is scrolled over too

If it is the first case, it is pretty simple, just make a vertical `LinearLayout` with a `Button` before a `ListView`

If it is the second case, it is rather complicated. As you shouldn't use `ListView` inside `ScrollView`, I suggest you make the first row of the `ListView` to be a customized view that has a `Button` inside. In order to do this, check out how to extend `BaseAdapter` and `LayoutInflate`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this button is not part of the listview.
Try to make a layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `ListView` is Hungry about height and will fill up all the height available in `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a relativeLayout  to do this :

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <Button android:id="@+id/btn"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="My Button"
      android:alignParentTop = "true"/>

  <ListView android:id="@+id/myList"
     android:layout_below="@id/btn"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Add Alarm"/>
    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This should give the desired layout.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [ListView.addHeaderView();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29)

This way the button will appear inside the ListView above the elements. Also, have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/).

Answer (score 0):

You can design the button in the own layout who are going inflated in the adapter and set the button visibility gone. In the adapter you must only check in the getview method if the psoition is 0 and if 0, make the button visible else make it gone. This way, you have a button in te top of the list and is scrollable. To make the button clickable, only implement the onclick method in the getview method. Its very easy.